# CMD command for starting a service remotely not running in code but runs on CMD

Tags: java, cmd

I'm building functionality to restart windows services remotely, but the string command that I built in code is not returning the desired output, copying the same command while debugging from the IDE and running it on CMD executes successfully.

I have tried changing from using method Process cmdOutput Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) to Process cmdOutput Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command[])
I have tried manipulating my string command in different ways to see if it will take it with no success.

I have looked at similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them are experiencing what I am experiencing

```
public void startService(int serviceId, String serviceName, String 
ipAddress) {
    CMDExecutor executor = new CMDExecutor();
    try {
        String command = "cmd /C echo "+ password +" runas /user:"+ 
username +" "+ "\""+
                System.lineSeparator() +" sc\\\\"  +ipAddress+ " start "+ 
serviceName + "\"";
        String result = executor.getCMDResult(command);
        logger.info(result);
}

public class CMDExecutor {
public String getCMDResult(String command) throws IOException {
    Process cmdOutput;
    cmdOutput = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(cmdOutput.getInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");
    return writer.toString();
 }
}
```

I'm expecting the below

```
SERVICE_NAME: serviceName
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 34916
        FLAGS              :
```

I'm getting part of the command back and nothing changes, service doesn't start.

Comment: Your command line is malformed: the `echo` effectively kills everything after, if it's an attempt to pipe the password to runas - you can't do that. There is a missing space after `sc` & the new line is not valid.

Comment: On debug mode, when I copy the value of command I get the below and pasting it on CMD runs fine meaning it's not malformed. What I do find odd though is, it requires a new line at "sc" to run successfully, hence I added it on my command.
cmd /C echo password runas /user:domainName\user "
 sc \\ipAddress start serviceName"

Comment: From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-) of class `java.lang.Runtime`: 
ProcessBuilder.start() is now the preferred way to start a process with a modified environment.

Comment: @Abra I tried that from https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/ but still got the same thing.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` and `Runtime` are not a replacement for Windows command prompt. On my Windows 10 machine, `sc` is an executable: `C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe`. So you should use `new ProcessBuilder("sc.exe", ipAddress, "start", serviceName)` Remember to start a separate thread to read the command output and another separate thread for the command error. If you need to pass input to the command, you can use method [getOutputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--)

Comment: @Abra I've already tried all that, thanks for trying to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for hours the simple solution was to split the commands into two parts, the credentials part, and the sc command part as per below. Now it works as expected.

PS. I opted to remove echo from the command to avoid credentials getting printed on the log file.

```
public void startService(int serviceId, String serviceName, String 
ipAddress) {
CMDExecutor executor = new CMDExecutor();
try {
String credentialsCommand = "cmd /C echo "+ password +" runas /user:"+ username;
String startServiceCommand = "sc\\\\"  +ipAddress+ " start "+ serviceName";
String credentialsResult = executor.getCMDResult(credentialsCommand );
logger.info(credentialsResult );
String startServiceResult= executor.getCMDResult(startServiceCommand );
logger.info(startServiceResult);
}
```